# php string concatenation (without) RTL

Tags: php, string, utf-8

Im trying to make URLs using Urdu strings. They are UTF8 encoded and RTL as normal. For all other cases, the default PHP behaviour is fantastic. It is automatically adjusts normal LTR actions in code to RTL as output.
Using PHP 7.2.13.

Like "a" . "b" . "c" in RTL automatically appears "cba" if those strings RTL flagged.

My problem is making URLs. Which are LTR separated by a slash. folder1/folder2/folder3. The funny output when all three strings are Urdu, it becomes folder3/folder2/folder1.

The following sample code which should work in both LTR and RTL languages that Im trying should show the problem:

```
<?php
$url_path1 = "اتر پردیش"; #translates as uttar pradesh (notice two words and a space)
$url_path2 = "کانپور";    #translates as kanpur
$url_path = "$url_path1/$url_path2";
echo "in Terminal: $url_path\n";
$html = <<<H
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ur">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
Url Path: $url_path
</body>
</html>
H;
file_put_contents("del-urdu.html",$html);
```

In terminal output (iTerm), it is appearing correctly (path1/path2), while when opening the generated del-urdu.html file, its coming differently (path2/path1).

How to turn off this behaviour for string concatenation?

Comment: It's OK. You see URL upside down because browser doesn't support RTL characters.

Comment: Im not talking about browers. And browsers do support RTL, even in the address bar. Im only talking about php side.

Comment: Please read the description of "rtl"!

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? Many people will have problems creating a script using Urdu letters (possibly including you) and also having concrete code will make intepretations superfluous because everyone can just check the facts. BTW: What's your PHP version?

Comment: The code given before was exactly which I wrote. Now I have tried more context and a working sample.

Answer (score 1):

it's ok . even though we see folder3/folder2/folder1
but it's folder1/folder2/folder3 in real.
Dont be worry .

Comment: You are right. My code which works wrongly to generate the URL, parses that same wrong URL correctly back. Very funny really, but I don't want my folder paths in URLs to change their places. Thats all.